# How can i make a program to update plug and play devices (Windows 8)

Tags: api, delphi

... like go to device manager, right click, and update.

I tried to make program on delphi, like this.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,   Dialogs, StdCtrls,mmsystem;

type  
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);   
    private
    public
    end;

var   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm} const  DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = $0018;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); begin
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_DEVICECHANGE, DBT_CONFIGCHANGED, 0);
end;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Not Delphi, but maybe this helps http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_152_Detecting_USB_%20Device_Insertion_and_Removal.pdf

Comment: You're more likely to get a good answer if you say what happens rather than simply that it doesn't work. Is it throwing an error (what's the error), making your computer explode, turning Mars into a black hole, something else? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When i start this program. Nothing is changes, i hear only song like some device was removed. And devices aren't updates. All problem that after srart my windows doesn't see my laptop batery, and when i update my devices in divece manager my batery is standing found. Will it be better if i share my delhpi progect here.

Comment: Where is the documentation that this code does what you expect it to do? I thought the system broadcast these messages. I don't see why you believe that you can do so.

Comment: I don't have a documentation, i found this code on the internet, but the comand WM_DEVICECHANGE uses to notificate user about changes, but i want to update my PnP devices and i don't know how can i do it.

Comment: Don't just try random bits of code for no reason. You need to find some documentation. What's more, why does your program even need to do this? It sounds to me like this is the wrong solution to whatever problem you actually face.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. Why do you need to send this message? This message is typically meant to be *received* from Windows, not *sent* to it. Are you writing some device drivers or something?

Comment: What does it mean to "update" a device? In over 20 years of using Windows, I don't think I've ever had to do that.

Comment: "Thanks for your comments", there are very "usefull"! I asked for the help to decide my problem with update devices. Only one quastion was help full, it was  Jan Doggen. But i don't have enough skills to do it.

Comment: Unless this is a very theoretical question, really sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: All of the comments were constructive and helpful. You should heed them closely.

Comment: Sorry, I got excited. It was my first quastion here:)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259697) Microsoft's article, you can use the following code to force reenumeration of a device tree from an application:

```
const
  CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL = 0;
  CR_SUCCESS = 0;

type
  DEVINST = LongWord;
  CONFIGRET = LongWord;
  ULONG = LongWord;

function CM_Locate_DevNode(var dnDevInst: DEVINST; pDeviceID: Pointer; ulFlags: ULONG): CONFIGRET; stdcall; external 'cfgmgr32.dll' name 'CM_Locate_DevNodeA';
function CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(var dnDevInst: DEVINST; ulFlags: ULONG): CONFIGRET; stdcall; external 'cfgmgr32.dll' name 'CM_Reenumerate_DevNode';

function ScanForHardwareChanges(): Boolean;
var
  dev: DEVINST;
  retval: CONFIGRET;
begin
  // Get the root devnode.
  retval := CM_Locate_DevNode(dev, nil, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);

  if (retval <> CR_SUCCESS) then
  begin
    // Writeln('CM_Locate_DevNode failed: ', status);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  retval := CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(dev, 0);

  if (retval <> CR_SUCCESS) then
  begin
    // Writeln('CM_Reenumerate_DevNode failed: ', status);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I made program based on it.But devices aren't update:( Maybe i made some mistakes. Again thank you for this code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your code. I made program based on it.

```
`unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, mmsystem;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
const
  CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL = 0;
  CR_SUCCESS = 0;

type
  DEVINST = LongWord;
  CONFIGRET = LongWord;
  ULONG = LongWord;

function CM_Locate_DevNode(var dnDevInst: DEVINST; pDeviceID: Pointer; ulFlags: ULONG): CONFIGRET; stdcall; external 'cfgmgr32.dll' name 'CM_Locate_DevNodeA';
function CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(var dnDevInst: DEVINST; ulFlags: ULONG): CONFIGRET; stdcall; external 'cfgmgr32.dll' name 'CM_Reenumerate_DevNode';
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

function ScanForHardwareChanges(): Boolean;
var
  dev: DEVINST;
  retval: CONFIGRET;
begin

begin
  // Get the root devnode.
  retval := CM_Locate_DevNode(dev, nil, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);

  if (retval <> CR_SUCCESS) then
  begin
    // Writeln('CM_Locate_DevNode failed: ', status);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  retval := CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(dev, 0);

  if (retval <> CR_SUCCESS) then
  begin
    // Writeln('CM_Reenumerate_DevNode failed: ', status);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
end;
BEGIN
END;

end.`
```

But devices aren't update:( Maybe i made some mistakes. Again thank you for this code.